# How can we find indices where `True` value exists along axis 1 in a boolean array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, boolean, numpy-ndarray

Here's a boolean array

```
In [102]: arr        
Out[102]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

And I want to compute the indices along axis-1 where there is an `1` and stop then and there and proceed with next column till I exhaust all columns. Thus, the expected solution would be:

```
array([ 1,  4,  5,  6,  0,  7,  8,  2,  9, 10,  3, 11, 12])
```

To explain a bit more about how the above result is desired: we start with column 1 and descend along axis-1 and we encounter `1` at index `1` and then again at index `4` and so on till where we encounter last `1` in that column at position `6`. So, we stop there skipping rest of the column because there won't be any more `1`s and then proceed to second column where we encounter `1` at index `0` and so on till we exhaust all columns. By putting together all indices we gathered so far should give us the result array.

I have a loopy solution but would very much prefer a vectorized one. How can we approach this? Any initial ideas would of great help.

Comment: A one liner: `np.flatnonzero(arr.T)%arr.shape[0]`

Comment: @kmario23 you question doesn't make sense. Even using `where` function you are using a loop, it's just hidden by the function call. So, saying you don't want a loop when you want to iterate doesn't make sense.

Comment: You never mentioned that you wanten to use `numpy.where()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [134]: arr=np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0], 
     ...:        [1, 0, 0, 0], 
     ...:        [0, 0, 1, 0], 
     ...:        [0, 0, 0, 1], 
     ...:        [1, 0, 0, 0], 
     ...:        [1, 0, 0, 0], 
     ...:        [1, 0, 0, 0], 
     ...:        [0, 1, 0, 0], 
     ...:        [0, 1, 0, 0], 
     ...:        [0, 0, 1, 0], 
     ...:        [0, 0, 1, 0], 
     ...:        [0, 0, 0, 1], 
     ...:        [0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=np.uint8)
```

Looks like `where` on the transpose finds the desired indices:

```
In [135]: np.where(arr.T)                                                    
Out[135]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]),
 array([ 1,  4,  5,  6,  0,  7,  8,  2,  9, 10,  3, 11, 12]))
In [136]: np.where(arr.T)[1]                                                 
Out[136]: array([ 1,  4,  5,  6,  0,  7,  8,  2,  9, 10,  3, 11, 12])
```

Answer (score 0):

Like said above. If you want a solution in the form of vectors then numpy is the best choice.

```
import numpy as np
arr = arr.transpose()
y = np.arange(arr.shape[0])
result =  list(map(lambda j: y[j==1], x))   
result = np.concatenate(result)
```

The trick is to use a separate array `y` for filtering index based on the condition.

Answer (score -1):

You should try with the numpy library in python 
Its very effective and easy to use.

```
v = [[0, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 1]];
import numpy as np
flattenedArray = np.array(v).ravel()

print flattenedArray
for i in range(len(flattenedArray)):
if flattenedArray[i]>0:
       print i
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this considering `matrix` as your input:

```
result = [i for i,x in enumerate(matrix.transpose().flatten()) if x == 1]
```

Comment: I'm not at all interested in a loopy solution. Please read the description in the question before posting solutions.

Comment: What do you mean by loopy? It's the only way to use a loop as you want to iterate.

Comment: One more thing to confirm that the question doesn't make sense.